# How do I check in which region of a map an object is located?

Tags: c#, unityscript

For example I have a character and two areas A and B, I want to test which area, A or B, my character is on.

Comment: _"How do I check the Object that ground...?"_ is grammatically incorrect in English. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I would edit it but creating a seccond question when the first gets close will not help. Edit your first question properly so it can be opened again.

Comment: How are you defining the regions?

Comment: The question is not well defined. The answer depends on the data structure representing the areas. Also, it is entirely possibly the character will be in area A and B simultaneously.

Answer (score -2):

you could make a function that returns the character's position coordinates and displays it on screen, the function being called everytime the character recieves input.

Comment: Create 2 box collider a that cover a separate area each and use OnTrigger function